# Trying to get submit button to work depending on what is chosen on dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with several questions. There is a mix. I have 3 dropdowns, a text spot for your name, your email and a comments text area. The last element on the form is a dropdown that has the choices of approve or deny. The submit button should take you to a different page based on whether approve or deny is chosen. For some reason when I hit submit, the button is not doing anything. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am using:

**html:**

```
<form name="iform" id="formapprovedeny" method="post" onsubmit="" onreset="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="formapprovedeny" class="iform">

    <br /><br />

    <label for="ApproveDeny">Approve or Deny:</label>

    <select class="iselect" name="ApproveDeny" id="ApproveDeny">
        <?php
        $values = array('Choose an option', 'Approve', 'Deny');

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $selectString = '';
            if ($value == $jsonData['ApproveDeny']) {
                $selectString = ' selected';
            }

            print '<option value="' . $value . '"' . $selectString . '>' . $value . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label><button id="button1" onclick="submitForm" type="button">submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="tempId" id="tempId" value="<?php print $tempId; ?>" />

</form>
```

**script:**

```
<script>
var onApprove = function() {
    submitForm('html_form_judge.php');
};

var onDeny = function() {
    submitForm('html_form_judgedeny.php');
};

$('.iselect').change(function(e) {    
    var dropdown = $('$value');
    var text = $( "$value option:selected" ).text();    

    var $button1= $('#button1');
    $button1.unbind('click');

    if(text == "Approve"){
        $button1.click(onApprove);
        return;
    }

    $button1.click(onDeny);    

});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen here: `var dropdown = $('$value');`

Comment: my reasoning was I was trying for it to pick up whether it was approve or deny as those are the values.

Comment: `$value` is a PHP variable - you can use PHP variables in JS like that

Answer (score 0):

First, change your submit button to something that actually does submit the form, i.e

```
<input id="button1" type="submit" />
```

second, to get the value of the select, you can simply invoce

```
var selectedValue = $("#ApproveDeny").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the submit button it calls the submitForm function and in your js you have onApprove and onDeny functions. need to run the function submitForm. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: submitForm

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your form a bit, feel free to modify as you see fit:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/7hs6M/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<form name="iform" id="formapprovedeny" method="post" class="iform">
    <label for="ApproveDeny">Approve or Deny:</label>
    <select class="iselect" name="ApproveDeny" id="ApproveDeny">
        <option value='1'>Approve</option>
        <option value='2'>Deny</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button id="button1" type="button">submit</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var onApprove = function () {
    alert('approve');
    //submitForm('html_form_judge.php');
};

var onDeny = function () {
    alert('deny');
    // submitForm('html_form_judgedeny.php');
};

var submitForm = function () {
    var selection = $('#ApproveDeny').val();

    alert(selection);

    switch (selection) {
        case '1':
            onApprove();
            break;
        case '2':
            onDeny();
            break;
        default:
            alert('Unavailable Action');
    }
};

$("#button1").on('click', function () {
    submitForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this will help get you going. Right now you have a form action of `formapprovedeny`. I'm not sure how you are handling that, but at first glance, it seems like that might be something that could be causing some trouble. Make sure it's a valid action.

I would also use a submit button type (unless you have requirements otherwise).

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="myAction.php" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
<form>
```

If possible, I would also seperate your javascript from your html. Create an external page, or create a script block just before the closing `</body>` tag. **If you are using jQuery, make sure to call it first.**

I would attach your form event to the submit event.

```
<script src="path-to-jquery"></script>
<script>
    $('#myForm').on('submit', funciton(event) {

         var actionURI;

         switch($('#ApproveDeny').val())
         {
             case 'approve':  
                 actionURI = 'approved.php';
                 break;
             case 'approve':  
                 actionURI = 'deny.php';
                 break;
             default:
                 actionURI = 'default.php';
                 break;
         }

         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: actionURI + 'any other params needed' ,
            timeout: 50000
        }).done(function(response) {
            // Handle response.
        }).fail(function(error) {
            // Handle error.
        });


         event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```